# Deno connection close event

Tags: deno

How to detect in Deno that remote has closed (aborted) the TCP/IP (HTTP) connection?

```
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 8080 });

for await (const conn of server) {
  conn.on('abort', () => { // <-- API I expect but doesn't exist
    // ...
  });

  const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);

  for await (const requestEvent of httpConn) {
    //
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Deno does not provide an API to know when a connection was closed, the most reliable way to detect a connection closure is to attempt to write to it, which will throw an error if it's closed.

The following snippet that tries to perform a zero-length write periodically will solve your issue:

```js
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 8080 });

for await (const conn of server) {
  const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);

  for await (const requestEvent of httpConn) {
    let interval;
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
            interval = setInterval(() =>
              // attempt to write a 0 length buffer, it will fail if
              // connection is closed
              controller.enqueue(new Uint8Array(0)), 
            500); // tune interval depending on your needs
        },

        async pull(controller) {
            /*
            const result = await someComputation();
            // in case you want to return some response
            controller.enqueue(result);
            // cleanup
            clearInterval(interval);
            controller.close();
          */
        },
    });

    requestEvent.respondWith(new Response(stream))
        .catch((err) => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            // check for <connection closed> error
            if (err.message.includes('connection closed before message completed')) {
                // stop your operation
                console.log('connection closed');
            }
        });
  }
}
```

---

The error logic can also be added to `ReadableStreamDefaultController` `cancel` method:

```js
const stream = new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
      // ..
  },

  async pull(controller) {
    // ...
  },

  cancel(reason) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    if (reason && reason.message.includes('connection closed before message completed')) {
      // stop your operation
      console.log('connection closed');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For now I switched back to Node.js where I knew how to do it. https://github.com/FreemapSlovakia/streamfinder/blob/main/main.js

Comment: @MartinŽdila since Deno 1.36.4 the connection drop is detect correctly, and `.cancel` will be called with `"resource closed"` reason

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK there's not an event-oriented API, but when the [connection](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.Conn)'s `ReadableStream` closes, you'll know that the connection has closed. This will also be reflected in Deno's internal resource map. Consider the following self-contained example:

A TCP listener is started, and is closed after 500ms. While it is open, three connections are created and closed (once every 100ms). When each connection is established:

- The current TCP entries from Deno's resource map are printed to the console.
- A reader is acquired on the connection's readable stream and a read is performed. Because the connection is closed from the client without any data being written, the first read is the final read (reflected in the read result's `done` property being `true`).
- The reader's lock on the stream is released. The stream is closed.
- The current TCP entries from Deno's resource map are printed to the console. Note that none appear at this point.

`so-74228364.ts`:

```ts
import { delay } from "https://deno.land/std@0.161.0/async/delay.ts";

function getTCPConnectionResources() {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(Deno.resources()).filter(([, type]) => type === "tcpStream"),
  );
}

async function startServer(options: Deno.ListenOptions, signal: AbortSignal) {
  const listener = Deno.listen(options);
  signal.addEventListener("abort", () => listener.close());

  for await (const conn of listener) {
    console.log("Resources after open:", getTCPConnectionResources());

    const reader = conn.readable.getReader();

    reader.read()
      .then(({ done }) => console.log({ done }))
      .then(() => {
        reader.releaseLock();
        console.log("Resources after final read:", getTCPConnectionResources());
      });
  }
}

const controller = new AbortController();
delay(500).then(() => controller.abort());

const options: Deno.ListenOptions = {
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 8080,
};

startServer(options, controller.signal);

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  await delay(100);
  (await Deno.connect(options)).close();
}
```

```
% deno --version
deno 1.27.0 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.8.168.4
typescript 4.8.3

% deno run --allow-net=localhost so-74228364.ts
Resources after open: { "7": "tcpStream" }
{ done: true }
Resources after final read: {}
Resources after open: { "10": "tcpStream" }
{ done: true }
Resources after final read: {}
Resources after open: { "13": "tcpStream" }
{ done: true }
Resources after final read: {}
```

Comment: Actually I need to know that remote has aborted the connection without reading anything from it. Use case is that client makes a HTTP request to run a long computation on the server but when it closes the connection pre-maturely then I need to get this event and abort that computation. I've also tried `conn.readable.getReader().closed.then(() => console.log('Closed'))` but promise did not fulfill when I hit Ctrl+C on pending `curl` command.

Comment: This won't work. Also you're consuming the HTTP body `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n...`, breaking the server (`Deno.serveHttp(conn)` won't work). Aside from that you may be getting `done: true` because there's nothing else to read, it does not mean the connection is closed, it means the data sent by the client was read.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228364/deno-connection-close-event/74229800?noredirect=1#comment131063428_74229800) @MarcosCasagrande There’s is no HTTP in the code I posted: it’s just a raw TCP stream.

Comment: Look at OP code, he has an HTTP server, and that's what his question is about.

Comment: And even then, the code is not reliable for TCP.